# Listening on open port using just HTML5 technology - is it possible?

Tags: html, networking, mobile

I'm creating a game with HTML5 and javascript, but am having trouble finding a way to get networking working. 
What I want is for one instance of the game to listen on a Websockets/http stack, while the other instances connect to it.

So far, I'm yet to find any way of doing it that doesn't require additional plugins or online services. (ie: Flash or silver light opening the socket and pumping messages back - Something that isn't acceptable for mobile, or an online server like Player.IO, which while much better than Flash, wouldn't work for Wifi networks that are disconnected from the Internet)

While the latter option is a compromise I'm willing to make, I was wondering if it's one I need to make, or if I could survive without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand what you are trying to, hope to be right.

Client One:
Plays game, listens to incoming data from Client Two

Client Two:
Plays game, connects to Client One

I'm guessing it's a P2P game? If this is the case, I think you want to look at [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/).

Otherwise, peer-to-peer is not really possible unless you run a mediator service that both clients connect to and handle it as a dispatcher.